# Extract data from largest date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having recods as below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| AcnttNo | Date1 | Balance1 | Date2  | balance3 | date4 | balance4 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 123     | 50282 | 3456     | 45465  | 56557    | 4556  | 324235   |
| 123     | 56757 | 23434    | 234235 | 344324   | 56476 | 5676     |
| 123     | 435   | 2434     | 2343   | 234545   | 24245 | 2423424  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For example:

for each `AcnttNo` there will be several rows of data for balance and date.
I need to get the balance for largest date.

I'm using PL/SQL developer and an oracle database

Answer (score 1):

If you want the row with the greatest date:

```
select
  *
from
  YourTable y
where
  greatest(y.date1, y.date2, y.date3) =
    (select max(greatest(yx.date1, yx.date2, yx.date3))
    from
      YourTable yx)
```

If you do actually need the balance matching the greatest date on that row:

```
select
  greatest(y.date1, y.date2, y.date3) as GreatestDate,
  case greatest(y.date1, y.date2, y.date3)
    when y.Date1 then 
      y.balance1
    when y.date2 then
      y.balance2
    when y.date3 then
      y.balance3
  end as GreatestDateBalance
from
  YourTable y
where
  greatest(y.date1, y.date2, y.date3) =
    (select max(greatest(yx.date1, yx.date2, yx.date3))
    from
      YourTable yx)
```

But I think what you *really* need, is to reconsider your table design. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've multiple dates / balances in your table, however, the below should get you something interesting that you can work on...

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM YourTable T2
  WHERE T2.AcntNo = T.AcntNo
  AND T2.Date1 > T.Date1
)
```